# How do I enable scrolling with a mouse in a TTY in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, mouse, 19.10, tty, scrolling

When I use [gpm](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/gpm/gpm.8.en.html) with a mouse in a TTY (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>), it allows mouse movements with a blinking cursor and such but scrolling with my mouse wheel doesn't cause any visible changes. How do I enable scrolling with my mouse in a TTY in Ubuntu?

Edit: My Ubuntu version is 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for you. You can run your tty remotely from inside of your pseudo-terminal. This will let you see everything that is displayed on the tty output (like SSH.)

You can run `tmux` in tty to start a session. The id will be displayed in the bottom left corner of tty.

Now go back to tty1 aka the desktop. From any terminal, run

```
tmux attach -t <id>
```

Replace  with the id from above.